# How do I change this simple alert into a photo instead?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to build a simple web application that is from a library book I borrowed, "Coding for Dummies". When I click on a button and I'm within 1 mile from a particular restaurant, I'm supposed to get an alert "You get a FREE burger". I got that working, but when I try to change the alert to a photo of a burger, nothing happens.

Here's the code:

```
alert(distance);

  if (distance < 1) {
   document.getElementById("effect").innerHTML="<img 
   src='https://i.imgur.com/W5ICO9j.jpg'>";
}
  else {
  alert ("Thanks for checking in!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's a link to the full code:
https://codepen.io/JoshNerd/pen/YOYxYM

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay, it's just that you replace immediately the html with these lines:

```
document.getElementById("geodisplay").innerHTML =
"Latitude:" + currentpositionlat + "<br>Longitude:" + currentpositionlon;
```

Comment that out (for test prupose) and you will see that the image is being displayed.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to understand why that worked, but it did. Thanks, Sid

Comment: @Josh because first you assign the image to the innerHTML and then you immediately replace it with that code, so your image is never going to be rendered as it is removed immediately. However, just mark the question and answered for future visitor and good luck ;)